# General Property Page (Project), programmatically change Target Name

Tags: visual-studio, j#

I´m trying to programmtically access to the TargetName property of Visual Studio General Property Page. I cannot find any way to do this meanwhile other properties, such as the Intermediate Directory, are accessible through variables such https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcconfiguration.intermediatedirectory.aspx.
We are following this example by @Daniel-Pistelli, to create a wizard, but we need to change TargetName property http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15297/Small-Application-Wizard

Is there any way to change TargetName?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Name property looks like the best match, try it.

Comment: Thanks Hans, but I try NAME and CONFIGURATIONNAME with no success.